# Unity - Laser activated objects using raycast

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to recreate a simple laser puzzle mechanic like seen in The Talos Principle -  where i have a laser emitter that i can move and rotate, and when the beam (raycast and `LineRenderer`) hits a specific object, that object will become "active". However when the object is no longer being hit by a laser it should "deactivate".

I am having troubles with the Deactivate part. Is there a way to tell the object that it is no longer being hit by a raycast, or add a collider to the `LineRenderer` maybe? Or some third way to tell the object that it is no longer being hit by any lasers.

Comment: What did you try? Post some code that show what is your issue

Comment: could you just run a check  every x frames to see if it is being hit? and then activate / deactivate?

Comment: I think your approach is slightly wrong; I would do it this way: All activateable objects should try to deactivate all the time ( a co-routine probably), but you cancel it when it is hit by a ray

Comment: @JamesLingham - That would be great, but how would i be able to check this from the raycast receiver?

-zedling - hmm.. good idea, i will try to see if i can make something along those lines that solves it for me

Comment: @darknath maybe a countdown variable which decreases every frame, and is reset upon raycast, something along the lines Doh09 suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your target is hit by a raycast, you could use the RaycastHit reference to acquire a script and update the cooldown.

Lets say we have RaySender and RayReceiver.

RaySenderScript

```
public class RaySenderScript{
    RaycastHit Hit;
    void FixedUpdate(){
        //SendRaycast and store in 'Hit'.
        if (Hit.collider != null)
           { //If raycast hit a collider, attempt to acquire its receiver script.
               RayReceiverScript = Hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<RayReceiverScript>();
               if (RayReceiverScript != null)
                  { //if receiver script acquired, hit it.
                      RayReceiverScript.HitWithRay();
                  }
           }
    }  
}
```

RayReceiverScript

```
public class RayReceiverScript{
    public float HitByRayRefreshTime = 1f;
    float RayRunsOutTime;
    public bool IsHitByRay = false;
    void Start()
    {   //Initialize run out time.
        RayRunsOut = Time.time;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Time.time > RayRunsOutTime)
        { //check if time run out, if it has, no longer being hit by ray.
            IsHitByRay = false;
        }
    }

    public void HitWithRay(){ //method activated by ray sender when hitting this target.
         IsHitByRay = true;
         RayRunsOutTime = Time.time + HitByRayRefreshTime;
    }  
}
```

1. Sender strikes Receiver with a ray.
2. Sender has a reference to Receiver, it uses GetComponent() to access it. It can then say receiverScript.HitWithRay();
3. Receiver keeps checking if it no longer is receiving, if it isnt, it stops being hit by ray.

Comment: Note that I dont actually send the raycast, I pretend that you take care of that in the "//SendRaycast and store in 'Hit'" comment at first in the sender script.

Comment: Very cool solution, thanks. This works great for what i wanted.

Comment: Awesome :-). Remember you can adjust the cooldown, it doesn't have to be 1f.

Answer (score 0):

Add all objects hit by laser to collection and check if current target is in this collection. If it is not there, then it is "deactivated".

Comment: This relies on the sender deactivating it though. What if the sender is destroyed? I suppose you could have an OnDestroy() which sets it not to be hit too. But all in all it would be better to have the target hit take care of checking whether or not it is being hit, as it is more isolated code wise and object wise then. Which is better and more safe for future operations.