# How to cast a ray from object that has got hit by other raycast?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to implement laser beam reflection behavior. I have a **laser** object named "BeamPoint" with `RaySenderScript` attached that simply casts a ray upwards.

**RaySenderScript**

```cs
public class RaySenderScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (gameObject.name == "BeamPoint" ||
            gameObject.GetComponent<RayReceiverScript>().isHitByRay)
        {
            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, transform.up);
            Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, hit.point);
            if (hit.collider.tag == "Effector")
            {
                RayReceiverScript rayReceiver = 
                    hit.collider.gameObject.GetComponent<RayReceiverScript>();
                if (rayReceiver != null)
                {
                    rayReceiver.HitWithRay();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Another object is "Mirror" that has to reflect a laser beam if gets hit by it. Mirror object has attached both `RaySenderScript` and `RayReceiverScript`.

**RayReceiverScript**

```cs
public class RayReceiverScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    const float hitByRayRefreshTime = .01f;
    private float rayRunsOutTime;
    public bool isHitByRay = false;

    void Start()
    {
        rayRunsOutTime = Time.time;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if(rayRunsOutTime < Time.time)
        {
            isHitByRay = false;
        }
    }

    public void HitWithRay()
    {
        isHitByRay = true;
        rayRunsOutTime = Time.time + hitByRayRefreshTime;
    }
}
```

Also whole area is surrounded by a wall (tagged *wall*) with collider - ray always will hit something. So, in my case, when the ray from "BeamPoint" hits the "Mirror" (with tag *effector*) the mirror does not cast a ray at all. And also `isHitByRay` variable doesn't turn into `false` after ray stops casting on mirror - I think it goes in cycles. It is the main question: why doesn't the mirror cast a ray when is getting hit by other ray, and when not - why doesn't the `isHitByRay` get `false`?

Comment: Note: In `Update` or `FixedUpdate` you should never use `GetComponent` repeatedly! Store the reference and re-use it

Comment: @derHugo actually my question comes from here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49646247/unity-laser-activated-objects-using-raycast). I don't completely understand that solution, but I guess there is a `timer` thing that always turns `isHitByRay` into false, and only when object is hit by ray turns into true. About the mirror object that has to cast a ray - there is condition in `RaySenderObject`, cause of that it should to cast a ray, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of small issue points in your code:

- As I understood every of your objects has both scripts. So first of all I would remove the repeated `GetComponent` call for the objects own `RayReceiver`
- Also add a check since it is possible that `rayReceiver` is simply `null` and therefore your method `HitWithRay` just never called. At least I would add a warning here.
- Then using `Physics2D.Raycast` it is pretty sure that the first hit collider is actually the one of your sender object itself! So you should rather use [`Physics2D.RaycastNonAlloc`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics2D.RaycastNonAlloc.html), filter the result and then use the first hit that is not the object itself.
- There is also no warranty in which order both `FixedUpdate` methods will be called. I would rather do it event based and enable a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html). This saves resources while there is no hit anyway.
- Also note that your `hitByRayRefreshTime` of `0.01f` is **very small** and probably even smaller then the rate of `FixedUpdate` itself (usually `0.02f`). The [original post you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49646247/unity-laser-activated-objects-using-raycast) rather used **`1f`** as value here. So your rays were simply immediately turned off all the time.
- Currently those are also not really "mirrors". If you really want to have a mirrored ray I would additionally pass in the exact hit position and direction and use it later for sending the new ray

So I would change your classes to something like:

```
public class RaySender : MonoBehaviour
{
    // would be even better if you reference this via the Inspector
    [SerializeField] private RayReceiver myReceiver;
    // enable this for the initial sender 
    // (using a simple bool is more efficient than string comparing the name)
    [SerializeField] private bool alwaysSends;

    // store the last hit object!
    private Transform _lastHit;
    private RayReceiver _currentHitReceiver;

    private void Start()
    {
        // Get your own component ONCE
        if (!myReceiver) myReceiver = GetComponent<RayReceiver>();
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        // if not always on or receiver not hit do nothing
        if (!alwaysSends && !myReceiver.isHitByRay) return;

        // except fot the first sender use hitpoint and mirrored direction
        var laserStartPoint = alwaysSends ? transform.position : transform.TransformPoint(myReceiver.incomingHitPoint);
        var laserDirection = alwaysSends ? (Vector2)transform.up : Vector2.Reflect(transform.TransformDirection(myReceiver.incomingHitDirection), transform.up);

        // give space for 2 hits in case you hit yourself
        var hits = new RaycastHit2D[2];
        Physics2D.RaycastNonAlloc(laserStartPoint, laserDirection, hits);

        // get the first one that is not yourself
        var currentHit = hits.FirstOrDefault(h => h.transform != transform);

        if (!currentHit.collider || !currentHit.collider.CompareTag("Effector")) return;

        // something was hit

        Debug.DrawLine(laserStartPoint, currentHit.point);

        if (_lastHit != currentHit.transform)
        {
            // update currentHitReceiver 
            _currentHitReceiver = currentHit.collider.GetComponent<RayReceiver>(); ;

            _lastHit = currentHit.transform;
        }

        if (_currentHitReceiver)
        {
            _currentHitReceiver.HitWithRay(currentHit.point, currentHit.point - (alwaysSends ? (Vector2)transform.position : myReceiver.incomingHitPoint));
        }
        else
        {
            // ouch! Hit somthing but RayReceiver not found here
            Debug.LogWarning("Ouch! Something without a RayReceiver was hit ...", this");
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
public class RayReceiver : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Settings")]
    public float turnOffDelay = 0.5f;

    [Header("Debug")]
    public bool isHitByRay;
    public Vector2 incomingHitDirection;
    public Vector2 incomingHitPoint;

    private void Start()
    {
        isHitByRay = false;
    }

    public void HitWithRay(Vector2 hitPoint, Vector2 hitDirection)
    {
        // stop evtl. running routines so we don't get concurrent routines
        StopAllCoroutines();

        isHitByRay = true;

        // get point and direction relative to this object
        incomingHitPoint = transform.InverseTransformPoint(hitPoint);
        incomingHitDirection = transform.InverseTransformDirection(hitDirection);

        // start the turn off routine
        StartCoroutine(TurnOffAfterDelay());
    }

    // after the given delay turn off the raycast
    private IEnumerator TurnOffAfterDelay()
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(turnOffDelay);

        isHitByRay = false;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please see my updated post

Comment: Omg, it was really helpful, and i learned a lot of new thinks. About the behavior that mirrors don't act as they have, thought make it later after solving other issues. But however, thanks a lot!

Comment: I think I've annoyed you a lot, sorry. But can you suggest anything for case when mirror1's beam gets reflected back from mirror2 on mirror1, in other words, is there any way for mirror to cast 2 rays at time or it'll become too complicated? If so i gonna just add checker if mirror casts ray it wont be available for new ray hits.

Comment: hmm, spontaneous I would say instead of using `bool isHitByRay` you could also use an `int isHitByRay` and use `if(isHitByRay > 0)` and then iterate through a list of `incomingHitDirections` and `incomingHitPoints` for casting new raycasts .... meaning it might get quite complex with adding the turn off behaviour etc but yes in general it should be possible ;)